# Position child <div> left or right relative to parent <div> depending on its screen position

Tags: html, css

I´m bulding a menu structure that will open a submenu on mouse hover. The submenu normally opens on the right side of the menu item.

My problem occurs when the menu is positioned at the right side of the screen, where opening the submenu will not show the full text of options, as it will be going out of screen.

I need a way to solve that by choosing to open on left or right depending on the position on the screen, or the space left for the submenu.

Here is the code:

```
<h1>
 Left Menu
</h1>
<div class='menu-container'>
  <ul>
    <li class='option'>
      Option 1
      <div class='submenu-container'>
         <ul>
            <li>Submenu option 1</li>
            <li>Submenu option 2</li>
            <li>Submenu option 3</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h1>
 Right Menu
</h1>
<div class='menu-container menu-right'>
  <ul>
    <li class='option'>
      Option 1
      <div class='submenu-container'>
         <ul>
            <li>Submenu option 1</li>
            <li>Submenu option 2</li>
            <li>Submenu option 3</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-container { 
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: grey;
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
}

.menu-container li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-container ul {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.option {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}

.submenu-container { 
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: red;
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   text-align: center;
   visibility: hidden;
}

.option:hover .submenu-container {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu-right {
  float: right;
}
```

I had setup a [fiddle case here.](https://jsfiddle.net/qjnkzh6b/2/)

PS: The solution shall not use JQuery as I´m using ReactJS for the final use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define a `left` and `right` property depending on whether the parent `menu-container` has the `menu-right` class. Then you can align the submenu accordingly:

CSS of note being:

```
.menu-container.menu-right .submenu-container{
  left: initial;
  right: 0;
}
```

```css
.menu-container { 
   position:relative;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: grey;
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
}

.menu-container li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-container ul {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.option {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}

.submenu-container { 
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   left:0;
   background-color: red;
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   text-align: center;
   visibility: hidden;
}

.menu-container.menu-right .submenu-container{
  left: initial;
  right: 0;
}

.option:hover .submenu-container {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>
 Left Menu
</h1>
<div class='menu-container'>
  <ul>
    <li class='option'>
      Option 1
      <div class='submenu-container'>
         <ul>
            <li>Submenu option 1</li>
            <li>Submenu option 2</li>
            <li>Submenu option 3</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h1>
 Right Menu
</h1>
<div class='menu-container menu-right'>
  <ul>
    <li class='option'>
      Option 1
      <div class='submenu-container'>
         <ul>
            <li>Submenu option 1</li>
            <li>Submenu option 2</li>
            <li>Submenu option 3</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css that you will need to add to make it work.

```
.menu-right .submenu-container {
  left:-100%;
}
```

If class `.menu-right` is applied to the menu item, then the menu div will be positioned on the right and .submenu-container will open to the left.

```css
.menu-container { 
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: grey;
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
}

.menu-container li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-container ul {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.option {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}

.submenu-container { 
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: red;
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   text-align: center;
   visibility: hidden;
}

.option:hover .submenu-container {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu-right {
  float: right;
}

.menu-right .submenu-container {
  left:-100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>
 Left Menu
</h1>
<div class='menu-container'>
  <ul>
    <li class='option'>
      Option 1
      <div class='submenu-container'>
         <ul>
            <li>Submenu option 1</li>
            <li>Submenu option 2</li>
            <li>Submenu option 3</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h1>
 Right Menu
</h1>
<div class='menu-container menu-right'>
  <ul>
    <li class='option'>
      Option 1
      <div class='submenu-container'>
         <ul>
            <li>Submenu option 1</li>
            <li>Submenu option 2</li>
            <li>Submenu option 3</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```